# In range of cells enter cell value based on preceeding cell

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to write an Excel 2010 VBA macro. As a programmer I’m experienced but programming on a PC, or PC languages such as VBA, I’m not experienced.

I want to look at a range of cells (D4:D100). If each cell contains a certain value, then I want to insert another value into the next cell. For example, I want to change each occurrence of `ESPN` to `773`. I want to change `ESPN2` to `772`.

If you can show me how to accomplish this, I *should* be able to make any additions needed for changing other values.

Comment: Is there a reason that a `VLOOKUP` formula against a table of values and returns is not adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you just might want to use a Select block:

```
For j = 4 to 100
    Select Case Range("D" & j).Value
        Case "ESPN"
            Range("D" & j).Value = "773"
        Case "ESPN2"
            Range("D" & j).Value = "772"
        'etc.
    End Select
Next j
```

As for VBA, I would start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383(v=office.15).aspx).

Please note that there is an unclear statement in your question:

*If each cell contains a certain value, then I want to insert another value into the next cell. For example, I want to change each occurrence of ESPN to 773.*

If you want to change each occurrence of ESPN to 773, then use code above. Else, replace `Range("D" & j)` with `Range("D" & j+1)`, if you mean into the consecutive cell, or `Range("E" & j)` if you mean the cell on the right of your occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. After playing around a bit with it, I got it to do what I want. Someone else suggested VLOOKUP. I suppose I should look into that as well just for my own education.